# typedef and enum or enum class

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, typedef, enum-class

I have an enum like this: (Actually, it's an enum class)

```
enum class truth_enum {
    my_true = 1,
    my_false = 0
};
```

I would like to be able to expose my_true to the global namespace, so that I can do this:

```
char a_flag = my_true;
```

Or at least:

```
char a_flag = (char)my_true;
```

Instead of this:

```
char a_flag = truth_enum::my_true;
```

Is this possible?

I have tried something like this:

```
typedef truth_enum::my_true _true_;
```

I receive the error: my_true in enum class truth_enum does not name a type

My guess is that my_true is a value not a type. Is there an alternative which I can do to enable this functionality in my programs?

Not ideal, but I could do something like:

```
enum class : const char { ... };
const char const_flag_false = truth_enum::my_false;
```

Comment: if you use enum class, you cannot avoid writing the prefix. verbosity is not a problem unless it hinders readability.

Comment: An enumerator of an `enum class` doesn't implicitly convert to an integer, so `char a_flag = my_true;` is wrong anyway.

Comment: I used a conversion above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was easy, the mistake I made was to use `enum class` instead of enum.

Yeah, so still a bit confused actually - I can now just use the values like:

```
bool aboolean = (bool)my_true;
```

Instead of having to do this:

```
bool aboolean = (bool)truth_enum::my_true;
```

Why is this?

Comment: Enums in C++ inherit from C, where it's pretty much just a preprocessor macro. Thus, it is visible in the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `class` from the `enum` definition. I'll assume that you are offended by implicit conversion to `int`. How about:

```
static constexpr truth_enum _true_ = truth_enum::my_true;
static constexpr truth_enum _false_ = truth_enum::my_false;
```

or simply

```
const truth_enum _true_ = truth_enum::my_true;
const truth_enum _false_ = truth_enum::my_false;
```

Comment: Okay I will look into this one sec I need to fix my code while I remember

Comment: What does static contexpr do? Actually, what does contexpr do?

Comment: `constepxr`applied to a variable makes it `const` and forces the compiler to compute its initializer at compile time. In this specific case, it's basically identical to `const` - I'm probably overusing the flashy new construct in places where it works but isn't really necessary.

Comment: okay I like that, but it is necessary? Once I removed the `class` keyword, it compiled absolutely fine. I can use `my_true` without doing `truth_enum::my_true` - should I be able to do this?

Comment: Apparently what I described above is the expected behaviours for an enum, but not an enum class.

Comment: @EdwardBird: The main reason for `enum class` is the namespace hiding *you don't want*.

Comment: @EdwardBird `enum class` does two things: (1) restrict the scope of the enumerators, (2) inhibit implicit conversion from enumerator type to `int`. I was assuming that you wanted to keep (2) and workaround (1). If you aren't concerned about (2), then plain `enum` is definitely the solution you need.

Comment: @Casey Sorry, should have made it clear! Implicit conversion would be good rather than bad actually...